# Rails: Value from Drop-Down always nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My form contains two options to enter a discount.

- via a Dropdown, or
- via a text field

**Dropdown:**

```
<%= f.collection_select(:discount, Warehouse.where(product: sale.product), :discount, :discount, {prompt:true}, {class: 'form-control'}) %>
```

*Collects data from a foreign table (Warehouse) and asks for the `discount` of the `product` record.*

**Textfield:**

```
<%= f.text_field :discount, class: "form-control", placeholder: "e.g. 99.00" %>
```

*Free to enter any value manually.*

Some JavaScript magic makes sure, that only one of those form fields is visible at once. The hidden form field receives the value "disabled".

My problem: Only when I submit the Textfield (and not the dropdown) the correct value gets saved. When I try to submit the value from the Dropdown it's `nil`, no matter if I leave it on "Please select" or let's say the value 99.00.

Here's my model:

```
class Sale < ActiveRecord::Base
 before_create :calc_discount

 def calc_discount
  if discount.present?
   discount = self.discount.strip.sub(',', '.').to_f
   write_attribute(:discount, discount) unless destroyed?
  else
   discount = nil
   write_attribute(:discount, discount) unless destroyed?
  end
 end

end
```

I do not understand why the loop gets past the first if clause, even if I select a value from the dropdown.

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: If you have two form fields with the same "name" attribute, the one which is further down the dom will override the previous one.  Is that what's happening here?  Is the text_field overriding the select?

Comment: @MaxWilliams my JavaScript pretends that, as the one that its not visible gets disabled, so the form skips it.

Comment: How are you disabling it?  You said something about setting the value to "disabled" - this won't actually prevent it from sending through in params.  If you set a disabled **attribute** on it, on the other hand, that **will** prevent it from sending through in params.

Comment: It works actually on other forms that I use, so that can't be the problem: `<select class="form-control" name="sale[product]" id="sale_product" disabled=""></select>`

Comment: Yes, that's a disabled attribute, which i said would stop it coming through in params :)  It wasn't clear in your question that that was what you are doing.